# Cart Page Coupon code move to with in the form cart like checkout/cart/updatePost/

Tags: magento2

I want to move the coupon code within the form of the cart page. I am not able to move. If I am calling with the phtml file within the form phtml, I am not getting the result.
Can anyone help me with this?
In the path of `app/design/frontend/Theme_Name/Module_name/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml`

Code:

```
<?php $mergedCells = ($this->helper('Magento\Tax\Helper\Data')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 2 : 1); ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('form_before') ?>
<form action="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>"
          method="post"
          id="form-validate"
          data-mage-init='{"Magento_Checkout/js/action/update-shopping-cart":
              {"validationURL" : "/checkout/cart/updateItemQty"}
          }'
          class="form form-cart">
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <div class="cart table-wrapper<?= $mergedCells == 2 ? ' detailed' : '' ?>">
        <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
            <div class="cart-products-toolbar cart-products-toolbar-top toolbar" data-attribute="cart-products-toolbar-top"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?></div>
        <?php endif ?>
        <table id="shopping-cart-table"
               class="cart items data table"
               data-mage-init='{"shoppingCart":{"emptyCartButton": ".action.clear",
               "updateCartActionContainer": "#update_cart_action_container"}}'>
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Shopping Cart Items') ?></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col item" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Item') ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col name" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Description') ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col price" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Unit price') ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col qty" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Quantity') ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col subtotal" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Subtotal') ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col actions" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('') ?></span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </table>
        <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
            <div class="cart-products-toolbar cart-products-toolbar-bottom toolbar" data-attribute="cart-products-toolbar-bottom"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?></div>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
    <div class="cart main actions">
        <?php if ($block->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
            <a class="action continue"
               href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?>"
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Continue Shopping')) ?>">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Continue Shopping') ?></span>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="submit"
                name="update_cart_action"
                data-cart-empty=""
                value="empty_cart"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Clear Shopping Cart')) ?>"
                class="action clear" id="empty_cart_button">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Clear Shopping Cart') ?></span>
        </button>
        <button type="submit"
                name="update_cart_action"
                data-cart-item-update=""
                value="update_qty"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Update Shopping Cart')) ?>"
                class="action update">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Update Cart') ?></span>
        </button>
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::coupon.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="update_cart_action_container" data-cart-item-update=""/>
</div>
    
</form>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('checkout.cart.order.actions') ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('shopping.cart.table.after') ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you explain properly with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Add move tag to your default.xml/.xml file,

```
 <move element="checkout.cart.coupon" destination="header.toplinks.right(Your destination name)" after="-" />
```

Comment: yeah , tried . but can not get.